# Is it possible to construct a lens which focuses all the light rays from an extended object in one point?

Tags: visible-light, refraction, lenses

A perfect lens focuses the light rays from an extended object (in a plane at a constant distance from the lens), in the focal plane corresponding to the distance of the object.

Now there is an infinite amount of possible forms of lenses. Is among those one form which focuses all the light rays coming from, say, a circular flat surface, parallel (in the mean) to the lens, which focuses all the light rays emanating from the circular surface not onto the focal plane corresponding to the distance (in the mean) between the surface and the lens, but to **one** point (which, if the lens can be made, probably lies in the focal plane)?

Comment: I am not sure if i get you question.. a 'normal' biconvex lens does focus the image to a point..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If such a lens was possible this would solve several problems. Unfortunately such a *Maxwell's Demon* is in conflict with physical laws, which more or less state the same:

### Unitarity of ray paths

From the symmetry properties of [Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations) optical paths must be bidirectional – exchanging start and end point results in the same path, just reversing its direction. That means that there is no optical element transforming two distinct paths onto one path. In a *normal*
 optical transformation like in the first picture you can map a set of rays that are distinguishable by their direction of propagation onto another set of rays distinguishable by their direction of propagation:[image: Mapping light rays emitted from one point in an extended source onto one point.]

Likewise you can map rays with the same direction of propagation but different positions onto a set of light rays that intersect, but can be distinguished by their direction of propagation:[image: Mapping light rays emitted into the same direction onto one point.]

But imagine a set of light rays coming from different spots in the extended source hitting the lens at exactly the same position. In order to make all the light from these rays go through the desired point the lens must map them onto *exactly the same* outgoing beam:[image: Mapping light rays entering the lens at the same point but at different angles onto the same ray – impossible!] This kind of mapping is not reversible:[image: Where should the beam go?]

### Thermodynamics

From the [laws of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_thermodynamics) it is known that in a closed system entropy must never decrease. Consider the ingoing rays and the lens as a closed system with a certain entropy, which is given by their disorder, e. g. their distribution in phase-space (position, direction). Then the *impossible mapping* from the previous example would decrease the entropy of the rays being mapped onto the same ray.

### Von Neumann equation

Changing into the picture of photons, one could use statistical description methods for point particles. [Liouville's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(Hamiltonian)) states that the phase-space density $\rho$ of a set of point particles does not change under time evolution:
$$
\frac{d\rho}{dt} = 0
$$
Of course photons are not point particles, but it turns out that a similar relation can be found for quantum mechanical systems described by a density matrix $\hat{\rho}$, which is given by the [von Neumann equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix#The_Von_Neumann_equation_for_time_evolution)
$$
i \hbar \frac{d \hat{\rho}}{dt} = \left[ \hat{H}, \hat{\rho} \right]
$$
with $\hat{\rho}$ being the density matrix of the state in the Schrödinger picture and $\hat{H}$ being the Hamiltonian. As photons propagating through free space and passive optical elements is an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian the commutator is $0$.

The fact that the phase-space density does not change prevents *compression* of the light into a phase-space volume smaller than the original source (which is bigger than a point source emitting in all possible directions).

### The solution: Pure states

The [von Neumann equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix#The_Von_Neumann_equation_for_time_evolution) leaves a possible setting where all light from an extended source can still be focussed onto one point (or let's say *diffraction limited spot*). In the case of a pure state $\hat{\rho}_{\text{pure}} = \left| \Psi \right\rangle \left\langle \Psi \right|$ with minimal entropy there is no decrease of entropy necessary to focus it onto one spot. This can be achieved with a [spatially coherent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_(physics)#Spatial_coherence) source, e. g. a source where the shape of the wavefronts does not change over time. Then, knowing the wavefronts in the plane of the lens one just needs to produce a phase mask that accumulates optical phase in each point such that a spherical wave is created:[image: A spatially coherent source has a very low entropy, hence it can be focussed to a diffraction limited spot.]
However, usual extended light sources are not spatially coherent. And making an incoherent source spatially coherent would again violate thermodynamics...

Comment: Another good explanation from xkcd: https://what-if.xkcd.com/145/

Comment: And the same question discussed on physics.SE: [Is it possible to start fire using moonlight?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/140927/is-it-possible-to-start-fire-using-moonlight)

Comment: So.rry for reacting that late...I only saw your (great!) answer now.

Comment: @A.P. ...actually, why **is** such mapping impossible? Couldn't the situation you show in the 3rd and 4th image not be realized using a laser and a single slit? The collimated laser beam comes from the right, hits the slit, propagates in coherent "rays" of constructive interference, and creates the corresponding fringe pattern on the screen on the left...

Comment: *Reversal*: A collimated and expanded laser beam is passed through a spatial light modulator (replacing the screen), which imparts on the beam the exact phase distribution required for it to propagate in the same "rays" of constructive interference, converge on the single slit, and interfere into a narrow, collimated beam propagating to the right.

Comment: @srhslvmn I'm not sure if I understand correctly the situation you describe. In your comments you talk about interference, which is quite difficult to treat in ray optics. If you wanted to model the 3rd image with a laser coming from the right, and the phase mask being a single slit, you would need to take several rays of the laser beam into account and consider their relative phases. But for diffraction, the wave picture is more appropriate. Also there you need to consider the lateral spread of the laser beam.

Comment: Why is this important? Because of the Heisenberg uncertainty. The divergence of the laser beam increases when passing through the slit, because the transversal extent is narrowed. A large fraction of the beam doesn't pass through the slit. That means, you can't create the spatially extended collimated laser beam purely from light which came from the left-hand side of the slit. (You would need to add some components on the rihgt side of the slit – basically the part that is rejected.)

Comment: @A.P. Hi, let's start from the fourth image and interpret it as a collimated laser beam from the right, diffracting (e.g.) at a single slit in the middle to produce a fan of fringes propagating to the left. When they light reaches a sensor or screen on the left, we characterize its amplitude and phase components. To reverse the situation, we start from a source on the left (replacing our sensor or screen) that emits exactly the amplitude and phase distribution we measured before. The light will reach the single slit in the middle and propagate as a narrow beam to the right.

Comment: In principle, this should be a pair of reversible scenarios, right?

Comment: PS.: I also don't fully understand the final sentence in your answer: *"However, usual extended light sources are not spatially coherent. And making an incoherent source spatially coherent would again violate thermodynamics..."* => I can imagine two ways to make such an incoherent source coherent: 1.) Move the source far away from the observation plane in order to reduce its angular size, which will increase its spatial coherence (van-Cittert-Zernike theorem), 2.) characterize the amplitude and phase of the incoherent source field and add a phase mask that exactly cancels the...

Comment: ...deviations from a planar wavefront

Comment: @srhslvmn [I tried to draw the situation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcQxG.jpg) The first image is a low-divergence laser beam impinging on the slit from the right. It has a low divergence, because its spatial extent is large, see for example the relation between the divergence $\theta$ and the beam waist $w_0$ of a [Gaussian beam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam). When it gets clipped by the slit, its divergence increases, because its waist is narrower.

Comment: Second image: The field arriving on the left side is sent back through the slit. Because it all came from the slit, it can be focused back into the slit without losses. But the waves leaving the slit to the right continue with the same divergence as the incoming beam instead of a collimated beam. Why? Because to form a low divergence beam, it takes a beam waist larger than the slit.

Third image: If the slit is large enough to let the collimated beam pass unimpededly, the situation can be reversed. But the beam keeps its divergence.

Comment: Concerning the spatially incoherent light source: That's right – _if_ you knew the wavefronts, you could straighten them with the right phase mask. But incoherent means that the relative phases are unknown. I can recommend checking out my answer on [What is a mode in quantum optics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/749865/169454) (_shameless self-promoting_). In there, I also link [a YouTube video illustrating how an incoherent light source looks in slow-motion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Y148V9gX2o).